# gunicorn + aiohttp + systemd

Tags: python, gunicorn

Пытаюсь запустить gunicorn + aiohttp + systemd

Если запускать напрямую:

```
/bin/gunicorn app:app -k aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --pid /run/gunicorn/pid
```

То всё работает, если через systemd выдает TypeError

app.py

```
from aiohttp import web

def index(request):
    return web.Response(text="Welcome home!")


app = web.Application()
app.router.add_route('GET', '/', index)
```

unit

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn/pid
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/srv/http/api
ExecStart=/bin/gunicorn app:app -k aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --pid /run/gunicorn/pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Получаю:

```
TypeError: make_handler() takes 4 positional arguments but 22 were given
Worker exiting (pid: 8718)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось запустить так:
в unit

```
ExecStart=/bin/gunicorn app:app -D -k aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --pid /run/gunicorn/pid
Type=forking
```

В ExecStart добавил -D